# create a sub-dict with first element in dict for every key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing different lists, I would need a fast & efective way to create a new dictionary containing same keys (better if I can be independent of key names) and one value of the list let's say the i-th

one example

```
 someDict = {'key1': [1,2,3,4,5],'otherkey': [.256,.221,.487,.454,.555]}
```

then the first elements (i=0) should return

```
subdict = {'key1':1,'otherkey':0.256}
```

the third element would be:

```
subdict = {'key1':3,'otherkey':0.487}
```

I could do some `for key,val in someDict...` to create new dict but i'm not sure it's the best option

Comment: If you want to create a new dictionary with all the same keys as the original, then you have to iterate over the dictionary.  Not sure why you are wanting to avoid that.  Maybe there's something in numpy that can do this and maybe it'll be done in C.  But with the standard library, not sure how you can avoid iterating over the dictionary.  You could profile different ways of iterating over it (comprehensions vs for loops vs generators, etc).  But it's going to look something like a for loop or a comprehension.

Comment: Do you need new dicts or would something like a pandas dataframe do? `df = pandas.DataFrame(someDict)`.

Comment: @saquintes i'm trying to avoid it because it could happen inside other loops and I want to avoid nesting if posible... I think i would go for a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need the new `dict` objects for, a pandas dataframe may be the best choice. It will generally be more performant for table-like operations. For instance, if your plan is to put those dicts in a list, the datatrame could be a good fit.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> someDict = {'key1': [1,2,3,4,5],'otherkey': [.256,.221,.487,.454,.555]} 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(someDict)
>>> df
   key1  otherkey
0     1     0.256
1     2     0.221
2     3     0.487
3     4     0.454
4     5     0.555
```

Comment: this could solve my problem with small or none refactor I didn't realize that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def ith_val_subdict(input_dict, i):
    return {k: v[i] for k, v in input_dict.items()}
```

Example:

```
someDict = {'key1': [1,2,3,4,5],'otherkey': [.256,.221,.487,.454,.555]}

subdict_0 = ith_val_subdict(someDict, 0)
print(subdict_0)
# {'key1': 1, 'otherkey': 0.256}

subdict_2 = ith_val_subdict(someDict, 2)
print(subdict_2)
# {'key1': 3, 'otherkey': 0.487}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `zip` in a list comprehension:

```
[dict(zip(someDict, vals)) for vals in zip(*someDict.values())]
```

output:

```
[{'key1': 1, 'otherkey': 0.256},
 {'key1': 2, 'otherkey': 0.221},
 {'key1': 3, 'otherkey': 0.487},
 {'key1': 4, 'otherkey': 0.454},
 {'key1': 5, 'otherkey': 0.555}]
```

*NB. this will truncate the values to the length of the shortest sublist, if there is an uneven length and padding is needed, use `itertools.zip_longest`*